# Seleccionar al menos un checkbox dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, knockoutjs

Necesito saber cómo puedo *generar elementos **checkbox** dinamicamente* pero dejando almenos un **checkbox** seleccionado.

Tener en claro que debe cumplir con la siguiente condición:

> Al menos un checkbox debe estar en checked o habilitado.

Debe parecerse al ejemplo que proporciono, pero con la condición de poder generar checkbox's dinamicamente (al presionar un boton por ejemplo que genere el checkbox y poder cumplir con la condición de que haya al menos un checkbox en 'checked').

Estoy utilizando **knockout js**.

```js
var viewModel = function () {
            
            self.isChecked1 = ko.observable(true);
            self.isChecked2 = ko.observable(false);


            console.log(self.isChecked1() ? value = 'seleccionado' : value = 'deseleccionado');
            console.log(self.isChecked2() ? value = 'seleccionado' : value = 'deseleccionado');
            

            // CHECKBOX 1
            self.isChecked1.subscribe(function (value) {
                // Ojo: se dispara siempre al cambiar de estado...
               console.log(value ? value = 'seleccionado' : value = 'deseleccionado');

                if (value == 'seleccionado')
                {
                    console.log("paso");
                    //self.isChecked2(false);
                }

                if(value == 'deseleccionado' && self.isChecked2() === false)
                {
                    //alert("Tiene que elegir al menos uno...");
                    self.isChecked1(true);
                }

            });

            // CHECKBOX 2
            self.isChecked2.subscribe(function (value) {
                // Ojo: se dispara siempre al cambiar de estado...
                console.log(value ? value = 'seleccionado' : value = 'deseleccionado');
                
                if(value == 'seleccionado' && self.isChecked1() == false)
                {
                    //console.log("paso por aqui");
                    self.isChecked2(true);
                }

                if(value == 'deseleccionado' && self.isChecked1() == false)
                {
                    //alert("Tiene que elegir al menos uno...");
                    self.isChecked2(true);
                }

            });
            
    }
        ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
    </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Test -->
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked1" />toggle
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked2" />toggle
</div>
```

Comment: te sirve un ejemplo sin **knockout**? en este caso no lo veo necesario.

Comment: Sí, me sirve igual.